# Output with three lines but txt file only with one line

Tags: python

I have a very basic question: one question about my code below:

```
    #Python code to scrape the shipment URLs 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import urllib

# read urls of websites from text file > change it to where you stock the file
list_open = open(r"C:\Users\**\data.csv")
#skips the header
read_list  = list_open.readlines()[1:]

import os

file_path = os.path.join('c:\\**', 'ShipmentUpdates.txt')


for url in read_list:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(), "html5lib")
    # parse shipment info
    shipment = soup.find_all("span")
    Preparation = shipment[0]
    Sent = shipment[1]
    InTransit = shipment[2]
    Delivered = shipment[3]
    url = url.strip()

    line= f"{url} ; Preparation {Preparation.getText()}; Sent {Sent.getText()}; InTransit {InTransit.getText()}; Delivered {Delivered.getText()}"
    print (line)

file='c:\\**\ShipmentUpdates.txt'
with open(file, 'w') as filetowrite:
    filetowrite.write(line+'\n')
```

In my output, I have three lines:

```
http://carmoov.fr/CfQd ; Preparation on 06/01/2022 at 17:45; Sent on 06/01/2022 at 18:14; InTransit ; Delivered on 07/01/2022 at 10:31
http://carmoov.fr/CfQs ; Preparation on 06/01/2022 at 15:01; Sent on 06/01/2022 at 18:14; InTransit ; Delivered on 07/01/2022 at 11:27
http://carmoov.fr/CfQz ; Preparation on 06/01/2022 at 11:18; Sent on 06/01/2022 at 18:14; InTransit ; Delivered on 07/01/2022 at 11:56
```

But in my text file, it is only one line:

```
http://carmoov.fr/CfQz ; Preparation on 06/01/2022 at 11:18; Sent on 06/01/2022 at 18:14; InTransit ; Delivered on 07/01/2022 at 11:56
```

I need the exactly same result of 3 lines in the text. Anything wrong here?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line of code in your loop keeps re-assigning a value to `line`, overwriting (replacing) whatever value it had before.  It's *only* that *last* value of `line` that ends up being written to your file.

I recommend you keep a list of `lines` as you step through the loop:

```py
lines = []
for url in read_list:
    ...
    line= f"{url} ; Preparation ..."
    lines.append(line)
    print (line)
```

Then, write that list with the `writelines()` method of your file.

Despite it's name, `writelines()` doesn't add line-endings (to... make a "line" of text), so you have add those yourself, `line+'\n'`:

```py
file='c:\\**\ShipmentUpdates.txt'
with open(file, 'w') as filetowrite:
    filetowrite.writelines([line+'\n' for line in lines])
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! This worked. Many thanks, Zach!

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
line= f"{url} ; Preparation {Preparation.getText()}; Sent {Sent.getText()}; InTransit {InTransit.getText()}; Delivered {Delivered.getText()}"
```

To this:

```
line += f"{url} ; Preparation {Preparation.getText()}; Sent {Sent.getText()}; InTransit {InTransit.getText()}; Delivered {Delivered.getText()}\n"
```

You need to concatenate instead of replace

Answer (score 2):

You are writing to your file **after** you finish your loop, so, in your case, you write the last line you have stored.
Try storing all of your lines

```
line += f"{url} ; Preparation {Preparation.getText()}; Sent {Sent.getText()}; InTransit {InTransit.getText()}; Delivered {Delivered.getText()}" + "\n"
```